# WordPress inserting forward slash before # and anchor ID

Tags: php, html, wordpress, divi

I'm trying to link two buttons on a home page to their respective sections on another page. The target page is /education and has two CSS IDs. One is named `training` and the other is named `recertification`. Normally, I just set the links on the home page to:

`/education#training`

and

`/education#recertification`

and then, on the education page, I set `id=training` and `id=recertification` as the CSS IDs of each of the respective sections.

But, when I click on those anchor links on the home page, something in WordPress, or maybe the theme is inserting a `/` just before the `#` so that I end up going to `example.com/education/#training` or `example.com/education/#recertification`. I just end up at the top of the page instead of jumping down the page to either of the sections as I intended.

I've never seen this happen before. How do I even begin to troubleshoot this?

WordPress Version - 5.8.2

Theme:

- Divi by Elegant Themes v4.14.4 (child theme)

Active Plugins:

- Gravity Forms: by Gravity Forms – 2.5.15.2
- Duplicate Page: by mndpsingh287 – 4.4.7
- Google Tag Manager for Wordpress: by Thomas Geiger – 1.14.1
- Rank Math SEO: by Rank Math – 1.0.78
- TablePress: by Tobias Bäthge – 1.14
- Thanks Redirect for WooCommerce: by Nitin Prakash – 3.0
- WooCommerce: by Automattic – 6.0.0

Inactive Plugins:

- Redirection: by John Godley – 5.1.3

Server Info: nginx/1.16.1

PHP Version: 7.4.26

Comment: First, are you sure that your permalinks are set to not have a trailing slash? Second, does that URL with the trailing slash still resolve to the correct page? If so, then the browser thinks it is correct and it should automatically scroll for you, WordPress shouldn’t have any effect on this. Is the page content coming in using JS?

Comment: I changed the Permalink setup to `/%postname%` with no trailing slash. That fixed the problem. Thanks!